# How can I get packages installed in venv to show up in PyCharm project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, matplotlib-basemap, python-venv

I am trying to use a virtual environment (venv) as the project interpreter for a PyCharm project. The virtual environment is called `venvtest` and is set up within the PyCharm project directory. That is, the project directory is `/Users/gitanjali/Desktop/plot_bridges2` and the path to the virtual environment is `/Users/gitanjali/Desktop/plot_bridges2/venvtest`.

I've installed a number of packages in `venvtest` through Terminal using pip. I'd like to be able to import three in particular -- basemap, matplotlib, and numpy -- to some code that I'm writing.

When I set the PyCharm project interpreter to be `venvtest`, those packages don't show up.

I've tried the following things to fix this problem.

I've made sure that the path to the venv is set correctly (`/Users/gitanjali/Desktop/plot_bridges2/venvtest/bin/python`).

I've called `pip freeze --local` from within the PyCharm project, and I get a list of all the packages I expect, since I installed them.

```
(venvtest) (base) DN0a229530:plot_bridges2 gitanjali$ pip freeze -- local
asn1crypto==0.24.0
backports-abc==0.5
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5
basemap==1.2.0
...
six==1.12.0
tornado==6.0.2
urllib3==1.24.3
```

However, when I look at the Project Interpreter window in PyCharm, none of these packages show up.

I've tried recreating the venv and invalidating caches and restarting PyCharm, but none of these have solved the problem.

What next steps should I try to get PyCharm to recognize the packages that exist in `venvtest`?

Comment: As you are saying you have installed dependacies using terminal. Have u activated terminal before installing your requirements?

Comment: if you want pycharm show what you've install, you need to do it with pycharm's way(answered below). But since you downloaded them with terminal, you can still use these package, but with no pycharm's autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing those by "file =>setting=> project interpreter=>addsign on upright => type in the package u want to install on top => click install package on bottom=>wait for the installation =>try it out!"
if still can't work, try [pycharm help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/getting-help.html)